# How to nest *ngFor without generating extra html?

Tags: angular

The next code...

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">{{child.name}}</div>
</div>
```

...generates the next html.

```
<div>
    <div>Mary</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>John</div>
</div>
```

My goal is generete single `div`'s as it follows:

```
<div>Mary</div>
<div>John</div>
```

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ng-container,  all the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let k of whatever">
   <div *ngFor="let r of k">
      {{ r }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

you can use the ng-container inorder not to show anything on the DOM